# why can't navigate to Downloads

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

I am trying to navigate to my Downloads folder. I got to `/home` but no further... 
I did `cd /home/Downloads` and `/downloads` and `sudo cd /home/downloads` (I don't know if the last is correct, but anyway) and also have set `set completion-ignore-case on` just to be sure, but still no success.

Comment: We only judge the people with bad questions. An arrogant man may consider yours stupid, but it surely isn't bad. ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cd ~/Downloads`.

The reason you can't `cd /home/Downloads` is because `/home` holds all users' home folders. There is no Downloads folder there. Say your username is johndoe. In this case your home folder will be `/home/johndoe`.

Either way, it is easier to use `~` which is a substitute to your home folder.